# Do not plot contourlines, just get the output for lines in colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two 2D-histograms, one with much more bins in each direction than the other. The both have the same original dataset. I want to show the higher detail histogram, and make a contourplot of the less detailed one. I also want the lines in the colorbar, to denote the levels of the contourlines.

However, if I add the lines to the colorbar (with `add_lines`), they end up in the wrong place, because the colorbar is from the higher detailed one, thus having lower values.

**Is there a way to get the output from** `pyplot.contour()`, **without actually plotting it?** Because the contourlines from the high detail histogram causes my pdf file to be too big. I tried setting the linewidth or color to `none`, but my pdf is still too big.

Comment: Can you show your code, and maybe mock up some sample data with the right kind of number of points for the resolutions to work?

Comment: What counts, in terms of the size of the PDF, is probably the number of contour vertices (the line width is irrelevant). You could plot fewer contour lines to begin with, or export the file to Inkscape and [simplify](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/advanced/tutorial-advanced.html) the contour lines by removing some vertices.